# SQL Query does not work in .net project, but runs properly in adminer/phpmyadmin

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Like above, my sql query doesn't work in .net project despite it work in adminer/phpmyadmin. That's quite weird. Here's the code:

```
SELECT mh.id AS `id`,
  IFNULL(ot.name, it.name) AS name,
  IFNULL(ot.name_en, it.name_en) AS name_en 
FROM udata.table1 mh
  INNER JOIN udata.table2 i ON mh.id= i.id
  INNER JOIN adata.table3 it ON i.type = it.id
  LEFT JOIN adata.table4 ot ON i.arg1 = ot.id AND i.kind = 46
WHERE mh.status = '1'  HAVING  ( `name_en` LIKE '%A%') LIMIT 0,30;
```

Adminer gives me 2 results different from runing the query in my c# project. I got this error there:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'name_en' in 'having clause'
```

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Please show us your C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Clauses cannot use query aliases, instead you must use the columns directly. So

```
HAVING  ( `name_en` LIKE '%A%')
```

Should be

```
HAVING  ( IFNULL(ot.name_en, it.name_en) LIKE '%A%')
```

Comment: Error looks like this now: `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'ot.name_en' in 'having clause'`